# Yarn module not found:

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

when I execute yarn mix in my project, i got this error:

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js 1:0-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './bootstrap' in '/Users/xxx/Sites/localhost/xxx/resources/js'
```

The bootstrap folder exists. Does anyone know what's wrong?

App.js:

```
require('./bootstrap');

import Alpine from 'alpinejs';

window.Alpine = Alpine;

Alpine.start();
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP or Laravel. I've tidied up the tags and the question for you

Comment: This error comes, when i execute yarn mix in my laravel project

Comment: So? Unless you can make a [mre] which proves the issue is specific to your Laravel environment and is somehow affected by some PHP code you wrote, then it's irrelevant. Since this is entirely a Javascript library, it's likely you'd have the same issue in any type of project, if you set it up the same way. Yarn is indepdendent of Laravel. We're not going to be able to help you much either as it stands, because we can't see your folde structure or where you're executing the command from.